# How to cross-compile neovim for Synology NAS

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, neovim, synology

As the title suggests I have issues cross-compiling *neovim* for my Synology NAS.

Host:

```
$ uname -srm
Linux 4.12.14-lp151.28.36-default x86_64
```

Target:

```
$ uname -srm
Linux 3.2.40 armv7l
```

**What I did:**

I downloaded the toolchain [armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL.txz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dsgpl/files/DSM%206.2.2%20Tool%20Chains/Marvell%20Armada%20XP%20Linux%203.2.40/) and extracted the contents to ~/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/

I downloaded the Synology Nas GPL source [Synology Nas GPL source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dsgpl/files/Synology%20NAS%20GPL%20Source/22259branch/armadaxp-source/) and extracted the contents to ~/devel/SynologyNAS/SynologyNASGPLSource/

(both above according to [this](https://www.bydavy.com/2012/01/compiling-linux-kernel-modules-for-synology-devices/) article.)

I cloned the [neovim source](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) to ~/devel/neovim/

I understand that I first need to run CMake to generate the Makefiles and subsequently run make to actually build the software. (at least that is what i found [here](https://gist.github.com/equalsraf/c52c2261ff3671ccbd32).) Accordingly I wrote a toolchain file as described in the [CMake Documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling).

```
$ cat ~/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-toolchain-file.cmake 
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 3.2.40)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9.3) 
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++) 

# where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/ /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/SynologyNASGPLSource/)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

I then tried to compile the third-party dependencies:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps
$ cd -p ~/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../SynologyNAS/armadaxp-toolchain-file.cmake ../../neovim/third-party/

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9.3 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Performing Test HAS_OG_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_OG_FLAG - Success
-- Found GNU Make at /usr/bin/gmake
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Performing Test HAS_NO_STACK_CHECK
-- Performing Test HAS_NO_STACK_CHECK - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps
```

To my naïve mind that looks like it should, however running `make` it gives an error about not being able to execute *host/minilua* which I understand it shouldn't be doing anyway as it is not being compiled to run on the host.

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target luajit
[  1%] Creating directories for 'luajit'
[  2%] Performing download step for 'luajit'
-- file: /home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/build/downloads/luajit/f0e865dd4861520258299d0f2a56491bd9d602e1.tar.gz
-- downloading...
     src='https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/archive/f0e865dd4861520258299d0f2a56491bd9d602e1.tar.gz'
     dst='/home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/build/downloads/luajit/f0e865dd4861520258299d0f2a56491bd9d602e1.tar.gz'
     timeout='none'
-- downloading... done
-- extracting...
     src='/home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/build/downloads/luajit/f0e865dd4861520258299d0f2a56491bd9d602e1.tar.gz'
     dst='/home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/build/src/luajit'
-- extracting... [tar xfz]
-- extracting... [analysis]
-- extracting... [rename]
-- extracting... [clean binary dir]
-- extracting... [clean up]
-- extracting... done
[  3%] No patch step for 'luajit'
[  4%] No update step for 'luajit'
[  5%] No configure step for 'luajit'
[  6%] No build step for 'luajit'
[  7%] Performing install step for 'luajit'
==== Building LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3 ====
HOSTCC    host/minilua.o
HOSTLINK  host/minilua
DYNASM    host/buildvm_arch.h
host/minilua: host/minilua: Kann die Datei nicht ausführen.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:641: host/buildvm_arch.h] Fehler 126
make[3]: *** [Makefile:113: src/luajit] Fehler 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/luajit.dir/build.make:74: build/src/luajit-stamp/luajit-install] Fehler 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:223: CMakeFiles/luajit.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Fehler 2
```

I found I can force make to continue regardless of errors. It then runs through the packages until it fails building `gperf`.

```
$ make -k
[...]
[ 72%] Performing configure step for 'gperf'
configure: loading site script /usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
=== configuring in lib (/home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/build/src/gperf/lib)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/usr'  'MAKE=make' 'CC=/home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9.3' 'CXX=/home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++' 'LD=/home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9.3' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
configure: loading site script /usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /home/jonas/devel/SynologyNAS/armadaxp-gcc493_glibc220_hard-GPL/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.9.3
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/jonas/devel/NeovimBuildForSynologyNAS/deps/build/src/gperf/lib':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
configure: error: ./configure failed for lib
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gperf.dir/build.make:106: build/src/gperf-stamp/gperf-configure] Fehler 1
make[2]: Das Ziel „CMakeFiles/gperf.dir/build“ wurde wegen Fehlern nicht aktualisiert.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:435: CMakeFiles/gperf.dir/all] Fehler 2
make[1]: Das Ziel „all“ wurde wegen Fehlern nicht aktualisiert.
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Fehler 2
make: Das Ziel „default_target“ wurde wegen Fehlern nicht aktualisiert.
```

Apparently the specific `configure` command does not recognise that I want to cross compile and I don't know how to tell it so as I am not manually invoking it to be able to pass the --host option. Apart from that I thought this whole CMake thing should have taken care of this issue. I also looked for *configure.log* but have no clue where to find it.

I should note that I was able to compile this software natively (i.e. to run on my host machine).

As you may have guessed I am by no means experienced in this matter and therefore even lack the ability to make out the actual underlying problem of the compilation failing. Therefore I would really appreciate help and hopefully get a better understanding of what is going on here.

Also this my first post and although I tried with comply to the guidlines I might not have met the expectations.

**Progress Made**

Following the hint provided by vsh i simply added `--host=arm` to the `cmake` command as I understand it is copied into the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` variable. `gperf` did In fact compile successfully but `make` stopped right after that due to errors

```
[...]
[ 75%] Completed 'gperf'
[ 75%] Built target gperf
make[1]: Das Ziel „all“ wurde wegen Fehlern nicht aktualisiert.
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Fehler 2
make: Das Ziel „default_target“ wurde wegen Fehlern nicht aktualisiert.
```

Guided by vsh's comment I also checked `neovim/third-party/cmake/BuildGperf.cmake` as well as `neovim/third-party/CMakeLists.txt`. In both files there are comments referring to cross-compilation.

From `BuildGperf.cmake`

```
# Gperf recipe. Gperf is only required when building Neovim, when
# cross compiling we still want to build for the HOST system, whenever
# writing a recipe that is meant for cross-compile, use the HOSTDEPS_* variables
# instead of DEPS_* - check the main CMakeLists.txt for a list.
```

From `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# Cross compiling: use these for dependencies built for the
# HOST system, when not crosscompiling these should be the
# same as DEPS_*. Except when targeting Unix in which case
# want all the dependencies to use the same compiler.
```

I'm rather confused by this. Apparently all dependencies should be built by the same compiler provided by my toolchain (as I'm targeting a Unix system) which of course will make them not executable on my host machine which leads to the errors above.

I will try to specify the `HOSTDEPS_*` variables anyway and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly look the repo I've found [BuildGperf](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/third-party/cmake/BuildGperf.cmake) which declares function `BuildGperf` that accepts `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`. You can try to find in sources where `BuildGperf` was called and which `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` it was given. There you can try to add `--host` option to allow having crosscompilation of Gperf

I was veery briefly looking first time)) in file I mensioned you can see the invocation

```
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${DEPS_BUILD_DIR}/src/gperf/configure
  --prefix=${HOSTDEPS_INSTALL_DIR}
  MAKE=${MAKE_PRG} ${GPERF_BUILDARGS}
```

here I suppose you can add everything you need to perform correct configuration of `gperf`